# Error in UseMethod("filter_") : no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "function"

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

Was trying to run this code

```
data %>% filter('region' != "Antarctica") %>%
    ggplot(aes(long, lat, group=group)) + 
    geom_polygon(fill="black", color ="white", size=0.15) +
    geom_curve(data = clean_flight, aes(x=src_long, xend=dest_long,
                                        y=src_lat, yend=dest_lat),
                                        alpha=0.25, size=0.05,
                                        color="white", inherit.aes=FALSE)+
    theme_void() +
    theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="black"), legend.position="none") +
    coord_equal()
```

I'm referring to this site
[Visualizing flight data with ggplot2](https://sjfox.github.io/p/visualizing-flight-data-with-ggplot2/)
Can't figure out why I'm getting this error and what I'm supposed to do about it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that you don't have a dataset named `data` in your environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because object name is not defined

```
data %>%
   filter('region' != "Antarctica")
Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "function"
```

and `data` by default is a `function` (check `?data`) which loads the specified datasets and its usage is

```
data(iris)
head(iris)
```

---

The OP may want to read the data first from `csv` or `excel` file

```
dat1 <- read.csv('file.csv')
dat1 %>%
   filter(region != "Antarctica")
```

Note that we don't need the quote around the column name

---

Based on the update, the data used is `clean_flights` and not `clean_flight`

```
library(ggplot2)
data1 <- map_data('world')
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
airports <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sjfox/sjfox.github.io/master/post/data/flights/airports.csv",
 col_names = c("id", "name", "city", "country", "iata", "icao", "lat", "long",
                                   "alt", "tz", "dst", "tz2", "type", "source"), na = c("\\N"))
flights <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sjfox/sjfox.github.io/master/post/data/flights/routes.csv",
 col_names = c("airline", "id", "src_airport", "src_airport_id", "dest_airport",
                                  "dest_airport_id", "codeshare", "stops", "equip"), na = c("\\N"))
airports <- airports %>% select(id, lat, long)
flights <- flights %>% select(src_airport_id, dest_airport_id) %>%
              filter(!is.na(src_airport_id) & !is.na(dest_airport_id))

clean_flights <- flights %>%  
  left_join(airports, by = c("src_airport_id" = "id")) %>%  
  rename(src_lat=lat, src_long=long) %>%  
  left_join(airports, by = c("dest_airport_id" = "id")) %>%  
  rename(dest_lat=lat, dest_long=long)  %>%  
  filter(src_airport_id != dest_airport_id)  %>%
  mutate(ordered_pair = if_else(src_airport_id > dest_airport_id,
                                paste0(dest_airport_id,src_airport_id),
                                paste0(src_airport_id,dest_airport_id))) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(ordered_pair)) %>%
  mutate(is_europe = if_else(dest_lat < 60 & dest_lat > 25 & src_lat < 60 & src_lat > 10 &
                             dest_long < 50 & dest_long > -15 & src_long < 50 & src_long > -15, TRUE,FALSE)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(is_europe))
  
data1 %>% filter(region != "Antarctica") %>%
    ggplot(aes(long, lat, group=group)) + 
    geom_polygon(fill="black", color ="white", size=0.15) +
    geom_curve(data = clean_flights, aes(x=src_long, xend=dest_long,
                                        y=src_lat, yend=dest_lat),
                                        alpha=0.25, size=0.05,
                                        color="white", inherit.aes=FALSE)+
    theme_void() +
    theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="black"), legend.position="none") +
    coord_equal()
```

-output

[image]

Comment: I changed the variable name. 
```
data1 <- map_data("world")
```
Now I'm getting this error:  Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'src_long' not found
In addition: Warning message:
Ignoring unknown parameters: data1

Comment: @HansikaSachdeva from where did you get the `clean_flight` data

Comment: clean_flight is the combined dataset of airports and flights